# Listview in xmpp android application

Tags: android

I have a doubt to be clarified. I am able to fetch the buddylist from my xmpp. I am facing issue to how to display them in list view. I am looking for a simple code to display these contacts in a list. Please help me in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To learn about the basics of the list view, Please see the [List View sample application](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) in android developer site.